# How can I keep baby dinosaurs alive?

Tags: ark-survival-evolved

I was playing ark with my sister when we noticed a fertilized egg dropped by my already tamed turtles. She looked it up and it told us we have to put a fire around it and so we got it out of the water and once we dropped it onto the land we put a fire around it.

After it was incubated the egg hatched and the baby turtles died within five seconds. My sister tried to look it up but all it said was to have the parents near the baby with food in there inventory. We tamed 2 more turtles and tried it again but the same thing happened any answer will help.

How can I keep my baby dinosaurs alive?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Baby dinos in ark need to be fed by hand until they reach 10% growth.
They have low food capacity and starve extremely quickly as you have noticed.
You need to put the food into their inventory directly for them to eat.

Make sure you have food available and don't incubate eggs if you have anything else to do.

Once they reach 10% maturity they will enter juvenile state and can eat from a feeding trough like all other dinos.

[Here](https://ark.gamepedia.com/Breeding#Caring_For_Babies) is the relevant section in the ark wiki.